# Compare 2 Datatables to find difference/accuracy between the columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

So, I have 2 separate datatables, that look pretty identical but the values in their rows might be different for instance.

**EDIT:**

I can have an unique ID BY creating a temporary identity column that can be used as primary key if that will make it easier. so think of ID column as the primary key than.

**Table A**

```
ID |  Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
-------------------------------------
1  |  Bob  |   50   |  150   |  35
2  |  Bill |   55   |  47    |  98
3  |  Pat  |   10   |  15    |  45
4  |  Cat  |   70   |  150   |  35
```

**Table B**

```
ID |  Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
-------------------------------------
1  |  Bob  |   30   |  34    |  67
2  |  Bill |   55   |  47    |  98
3  |  Pat  |   100  |  15    |  45
4  |  Cat  |   70   |  100   |  20
```

Output Should be:

**Table C**

```
ID |  Name | TableAValue1 | TableBValue1 | DiffValue1 ....Samething for Value2 .....samething for value3
------------------------------------------------------
1  |  Bob  |   50         |   30         |    20          
2  |  Bill |   55         |   55         |    0               
3  |  Pat  |   10         |   100        |    90                
4  |  Cat  |   70         |   70         |    0
```

I Know the tedious method to do this is by using a `forloop` and looping through each row comparing column rows with each other. But I am not sure how to create a new Table C with the results I want. Also I think there might be a simpler solution using `Linq` which I am not very familiar with but I would be interested in the solution with `linq` if it faster and less lines of code. **I am looking for the most optimal/efficient way of going about this. as these datatables can be anywhere between 5,000 to 15,000+ rows in size so memory usage becomes an issue.**

Comment: LINQ internally uses loops, since your IDs are not unique you want a row by row comparison. I am not sure if LINQ would improve the performance.

Comment: How are you matching up the rows between the two tables? Are they keyed by Name? Or by the combination or ID and Name? Or can we assume that each table has the same number of rows, and the ordering of the rows matches exactly between them?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes each table will have same amount of rows/columns and the columns names will be the same for both tables as well. but there is just no primary key that is unique in the rows between the tables..

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I have edited my post please see updated question, ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @PrakashChennupati: That's fine. I would have suggested using the `.Zip()` LINQ function to combine the two, which would have been slightly faster than doing a join on an ID. Another question: Does your output have to be in the form of a DataTable? With memory and performance being an issue, you might be better off using a list of objects that represent the columns in your output, rather than a DataTable. But I don't know how you plan to use the data afterward.

Comment: the reason i am using datatable, was cause my data is sent via CSV file and I convert that csv into a datatable pretty easily, compare these differences and load that datatable back into the database with the differences attached. I just thought i would be more readable and easier to maintain code via datatable vs using objects/lists/arrays.

Comment: @PrakashChennupati: If you have a utility that makes it quick and easy to load an entire datatable into a database table, then that makes sense. If you're doing manipulations on the data in the code, I find it easier (and faster) to say `item.DiffValue1` than `row.Field<int>("DiffValue1")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tableC = new DataTable();
tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID"));
tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TableAValue1"));
tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TableBValue1"));
tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DiffValue1"));
foreach (DataRow rowA in tableA.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow rowB in tableB.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rowA["ID"]) == Convert.ToInt32(rowB["ID"]) &&
            rowA["Name"].ToString() == rowB["Name"].ToString() &&
            Convert.ToInt32(rowA["Value1"]) != Convert.ToInt32(rowB["Value1"]))
        {
            var newRow = tableC.NewRow();
            newRow["ID"] = rowA["ID"];
            newRow["Name"] = rowA["Name"];
            newRow["TableAValue1"] = rowA["Value1"];
            newRow["TableBValue1"] = rowB["Value1"];
            newRow["DiffValue1"] = Convert.ToInt32(rowA["Value1"]) - Convert.ToInt32(rowB["Value1"]);
            tableC.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`LINQ` is not faster, at least not in general. But it can help to increase readability.

You can use `Enumerable.Join` which might be more efficient than nested loops, but you need a loop to fill your third table anyway. So the first two columns are the identifiers and the rest are the values:

```
var query = from r1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
            join r2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
            on new { ID = r1.Field<int>("ID"), Name = r1.Field<string>("Name") }
            equals new { ID = r2.Field<int>("ID"), Name = r2.Field<string>("Name") }
            select new { r1, r2 };

var columnsToCompare = table1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(2);

foreach (var rowInfo in query)
{
    var row = table3.Rows.Add();
    row.SetField("ID", rowInfo.r1.Field<int>("ID"));
    row.SetField("Name", rowInfo.r1.Field<int>("Name"));
    foreach (DataColumn col in columnsToCompare)
    { 
        int val1 = rowInfo.r1.Field<int>(col.ColumnName);
        int val2 = rowInfo.r2.Field<int>(col.ColumnName);
        int diff = (int)Math.Abs(val1-val2);
        row.SetField(col.ColumnName, diff);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ, create an anonymous type as follows

```
    var joinedRows = (from rowA in TableA.AsEnumerable()
                      from rowB in TableB.AsEnumerable()
                      where rowA.Field<String>("Name") == rowB.Field<String>("Name")
                      select new
                                 {
                                     ID = rowA.Field<int>("ID"),
                                     Name = rowA.Field<String>("Name"),
                                     TableAValue1 = rowA.Field<int>("Value1"),
                                     TableBValue1 = rowB.Field<int>("Value1"),
                                     DiffValue1 = Math.Abs(rowA.Field<int>("Value1") - rowB.Field<int>("Value1")),
                                     TableAValue2 = rowA.Field<int>("Value2"),
                                     TableBValue2 = rowB.Field<int>("Value2"),
                                     DiffValue2 = Math.Abs(rowA.Field<int>("Value2") - rowB.Field<int>("Value2")),
                                     TableAValue3 = rowA.Field<int>("Value3"),
                                     TableBValue3 = rowB.Field<int>("Value3"),
                                     DiffValue3 = Math.Abs(rowA.Field<int>("Value3") - rowB.Field<int>("Value3"))
                                 });
```

Table.AsEnumerable() will give you an IEnumerable(of DataRow)
row.Field will cast it to the correct type for you

You can now use the anonymous type of joinedRows and create your new dataTable from it

Answer (score 1):

This uses a strategy similar to kippermand's, but will probably perform slightly better on large sets of data by avoiding the `O(n²)` complexity of checking every ID against every other ID, and by reusing the values extracted from the data table:

```
// joining by row location
var joinedTableRows =
    dt1.AsEnumerable().Zip(dt2.AsEnumerable(),
        (r1, r2) => new{r1, r2});
// or, joining by ID
var joinedTableRows2 =
    dt1.AsEnumerable().Join(dt2.AsEnumerable(),
        r => r.Field<int>("ID"),
        r => r.Field<int>("ID"),
        (r1, r2) => new{r1, r2});

var result =
    from row in joinedTableRows
    let rowA = row.r1
    let rowB = row.r2
    let tableAValue1 = rowA.Field<int>("Value1")
    let tableBValue1 = rowB.Field<int>("Value1")
    let tableAValue2 = rowA.Field<int>("Value2")
    let tableBValue2 = rowB.Field<int>("Value2")
    let tableAValue3 = rowA.Field<int>("Value3")
    let tableBValue3 = rowB.Field<int>("Value3")
    select new
    {
        ID = row.r1.Field<int>("ID"),
        Name = row.r1.Field<string>("Name"),
        TableAValue1 = tableAValue1,
        TableBValue1 = tableBValue1,
        DiffValue1 = Math.Abs(tableAValue1 - tableBValue1),
        TableAValue2 = tableAValue2,
        TableBValue2 = tableBValue2,
        DiffValue2 = Math.Abs(tableAValue2 - tableBValue2),
        TableAValue3 = tableAValue3,
        TableBValue3 = tableBValue3,
        DiffValue3 = Math.Abs(tableAValue3 - tableBValue3)
    };
```

Depending on how your data needs to be consumed, you could either declare a class matching this anonymous type, and consume that directly (which is what I'd prefer), or you can create a DataTable from these objects, if you have to.