# Compare datatables and save difference

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project that it has to send a notifications every time a failure is solved. Right now, I run a SQL Query and save it in a datable to later compare it with new data, it is something like this:

First table:

```
ID  Source  Zone    Time    TimeEnd

1   TGS1    FABRIC1 10:00   10:03
2   TGS2    FABRIC2 10:06
3   TGS3    FABRIC3 10:11
```

Second table:

```
ID  Source  Zone    Time    TimeEnd

1   TGS1    FABRIC1 10:00   10:03
2   TGS2    FABRIC2 10:06   10:07
3   TGS3    FABRIC3 10:11   10:15
4   TGS4    FABRIC3 10:23
```

I want to compare them both and make a third one, with only the differences (solved repairs), like so:

```
ID  Source  Zone    Time    TimeEnd
2   TGS2    FABRIC2 10:06   10:07
3   TGS3    FABRIC3 10:11   10:15
```

But my code does not seem to work, this is what I'm using:

```
Dim tableForMerge As DataTable
Dim tableChanges As DataTable = Nothing
Dim primaryKey(0) AS DataColumn

'=== Merge the old data, copied on the form load ===
tableForMerge.Merge(tableCurrentData)
tableForMerge.AcceptChanges()

'=== Primarykey to correctly compare the two tables ===
primaryKey(0) = tableForMerge.Columns("ID")
tableForMerge.PrimaryKey = primaryKey

'==== Get current data in the dataset and merge it with the old one ===
tableCurrentData = MyDataset.originalData.Copy
tableForMerge.Merge(tableCurrentData,False)

'=== see changes in the table ===
tableChanges = tableForMerge.getChanges(DataRowState.Modified)
```

I've searched here for a solution but did not find it and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it seems like the merge it's working but not the getChanges, it always returns nothing. 
I can't use LINQ because the machine that will run the app has an old .NET framework and I'm not allowed to change it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this something you could just do in SQL?

Comment: I only have permission to do SELECT queries. I'm not allowed to save triggers, procedures or functions or modify any table in the SQLServer

Comment: Looks like you could do this with a simple join or a not in clause, though I'm not quite sure how you're getting your results. Why isn't the TGS1 row in your expected output?

Comment: What is the `getChanges` content? Since you're using .NET 1.1/2.0, the possible solution may involve loops like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666138/compare-2-datatables-to-find-difference-accuracy-between-the-columns). If you want to use SELECT statements, better to use `SqlCommand` with parameterized query and store results inside `DataTable`.

Comment: TGS1 it's not a expected result because it's an already solved repair, i want to have only new rows to send an email with It. GetChanges content is always empty, It does not seem to work. I will try to do It only with SQL, thanks you both for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments this can be done in SQL.  Just unsure if your blank data is an empty string or NULL.  Assuming Null in my answer.

This joins the two tables with a left join on the id based on table1.  Showing only the data from table2 when table1's TimeEnd has no value, and table2's TimeEnd has a value.

```
 SELECT tbl2.*
   FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
  WHERE tbl1.TimeEnd is Null AND tbl2.TimeEnd is not Null
```

---

Though an alternate solution if you know the last time you've searched, and the TimeEnd is a date/time stamp.  You could simply search the main table for anything past that the previous time, instead of dealing with a full temporary copy of the table in an earlier state.

In other words it would return a list of all solved repairs after the specified time.  Which is what I would do if I were setting up an automated e-mailing task.

```
SELECT tbl.*
  FROM tbl 
 WHERE tbl.TimeEnd > @previousTimeChecked AND tbl.TimeEnd is not Null
```

*Note: None of these queries were tested, just written in notepad. :p*